# Django data channeling from views

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-views

I want to channel my data in the view. The problem with the method below, which works fine, is that i cannot use try except (EAFP approach).

How can I iterate over `dev` object to build the data in the context dictionary? So that i can use try except?

I want to catch filter errors for example filter can be filter() or can have an expression that does not exist in the model or in the database.

```
def DeviceDetailView(request, device_name):

    dev = DeviceDetail.objects.values()

    context = {
    'data': [(a, appl.objects.filter(device_name=device_name).values_list(a['value'], flat=True)[:1]) for a in dev],
    }

    return render(request, 'applications/device.detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to use `try-except`?

Comment: in the filtering `appl.objects.filter()`... For Except i need to use another filter. The code will get ugly if i add more code in the list above.

Comment: Why do you want to force yourself to use `try-except`? Do you suspect an Exception is going to be raised in your code?

Comment: Yes, filtering is dynamic which sometimes it doesn't accept any argument. I want to not use filtering in the except

Comment: Build up the filtering logic in if statements and then apply it at the end? You should also include what error(s) you're trying to catch in the try/except.

Comment: i have explained why i want to catch errors. Can you give an answer how can i do it? the same way as my example